# Why I can not pass arguments to python file using ProcessStartInfo() in C#

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am implementing an image classification application runs on TensorFlow.
I was able to get all results successfully using Python and now in the process of implementing a GUI using C# which I am familiar with. I am using the example at [here](https://medium.com/emoney-engineering/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5). My issue is that I can not pass arguments as I do in Python where I type them next to python file.

This is how I have setup the header info

```
string cmd = @"c:\flowers\label_image.py";
string args = @"--input_layer=Placeholder --output_layer=final_result --image=c:/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg";
            start.FileName = @"C:\Users\pubud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe";                
start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd, args);
```

When execute above I get

```
"c:\flowers\label_image.py" "--input_layer=Placeholder --output_layer=final_result --image=c:/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg"
2019-01-05 08:55:25.369320: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\flowers\label_image.py", line 127, in <module>
    input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name)
  File "C:\Users\pubud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3618, in get_operation_by_name
    return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=False, allow_operation=True)
  File "C:\Users\pubud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3490, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "C:\Users\pubud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3544, in _as_graph_element_locked
    (repr(name), types_str))
ValueError: Name 'import/Placeholder --output_layer=final_result --image=c:/flower_photos/daisy/21652746_cc379e0eea_m.jpg' appears to refer to a Tensor, not a Operation.
```

Issue here is that label_image.py do not understand the parameters and try running defaults.

But If I remove the arguments and call label_image.py with defaults hard-coded into the py file, its working fine.

```
start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"", cmd);
```

Why is this not understanding my arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

Following provided Format systax is causing the error. (It is passing " " in to the Arguments string)

```
start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd, args);
```

So it is changed to the following :

```
start.Arguments = string.Format(@"{0} {1}", cmd, args);
```

It's working now.